# Is there an alternative to the 'insert' key?

Tags: logitech-keyboard

On my logitech keyboard the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key has been replaced by a doubly big delete button.

I don't mind, because I never use insert mode.

However, very occasionally I end up in insert mode. Of course, when this happens, I don't have an <kbd>Insert</kbd> key to get me back out. So I need a reboot

How can this happen?

Is there another shortcut that gets me into 'insert' mode?

Comment: If this is in Microsoft Office, then double-click the INS/OVR indicator in the status bar.

Comment: Your keyboard doesn't have the insert key on top? I mean, like this one: http://tech2.in.com/media/images/2009/Jan/img_112742_logitech-desktop.jpg

Comment: they deserve a beating for modifying keyboards like this!

Answer (score 32):

Remove num-lock and press <kbd>0</kbd>         on the numpad.

Comment: Note: The num-lock key disappeared from your post.

Comment: @Huppie: I think it's funny the way it is. I'm envisioning someone trying to pop the keycap off and pressing it while it's in the palm of their hand. Hey, it's Friday and I need some amusement, what can I say?

Comment: @Huppie: Thanks. didn't notice that. Must have deleted it by mistake when editing it.

@Dennis: That made me lol :)

Comment: What if I also don't have a numpad, nor any e.g. function-activated numpad keys?

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

I just read somewhere that, for example on the Logitech LX-501 keyboard, the Insert is on one of the round blue buttons (next to the function keys). On some Microsoft keyboards one needs to hold down some Fn-key and press PrtScr.

So: are you sure there's no Insert key on your keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

trex279's answer is probably the best one you're going to find but I thought I'd throw out an alternative:

Open the **On-Screen Keyboard** (on WinXP: Start > All Programs > Accessories > Accesibility > On-Screen Keyboard) and click the <kbd>ins</kbd> key.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> on the number pad to go into `Insert` mode.

On a laptop you may have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd> to get to `0` on the num pad.

E.g. on my Dell Latitude I had to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to turn off overtype mode.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very specific to one particular situation. It will not necessarily work in other situations. I have a Logitech k750-mac solar wireless keyboard. I am running on a MacBook Pro accessing a Windows 10 desktop remotely. In this situation, I use the **Shift + number-pad-0 key**. But *it only works with some software!* Furthermore, I suspect the answer to this question will be more or less a table of situations with solutions specific to those situations, rather than a general solution.

Comment: This worked for me. In order to use shift+insert I had press BOTH shift keys and the number-pad-0.

Comment: SHIFT+0 saved me! tks mate

Answer (score 1):

On Logitech K811, hold <kbd>fn</kbd> while clicking the <kbd>delete</kbd> key to get <kbd>insert</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

On a small laptop, like the new HP G5, you have to activate the NumLock to access the numbers pad, then use **shift + 0**.
It is not written, but it works to activate and deactivate this stupid feature.

Answer (score 1):

on a Microsoft All in one media keyboard (with no number pad), I found <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> works as the substitute for the Ins key

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible via Microsoft's Power Toys addon. Install Power Toys, then configure the "Keyboard Manager" element:

1. Enable keyboard manager
2. Click remap a shortcut
3. Pick an obscure shortcut combination you want to use to toggle insert on and off
4. Map it to "insert"

Whenever it goes awry, just use the key combo to put it right again.